# Problem downloading add-on dictionaries on Google Keyboard (Gboard), can it be downloaded in different way?

Tags: languages, gboard, dictionary

Using Lenovo A6010 Plus with the latest update of Android 5.0.2. Here is the problem:

When I go to **GBoard Settings > Dictionary > Add-on dictionaries**, I simply look for the language I want to add and mark it. The status changes to "Downloading", but in a second, it goes back to "Available" again, and no downloading starts or language dictionary added.

[image: Marking the language to download]
[image: Automatically stopping the download]

Google Keyboard comes with the phone and it can't be uninstalled. The problem occurs after updating Google Keyboard to Gboard (the new Google Keyboard name).
What I tried:

- Restarting the phone.
- Allowing unknown source installation
- Trying the same exact steps on another phone, on the same WiFi, and verifying it works ***(is there any way to transfer the dictionary after downloading it from one phone to another ?)***
- Trying mobile data and disabling WiFi
- Uninstalling the update and installing it again

Looking forward to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same phone and the same problem.

Yesterday, I have installed "Norton Clean, Junk Removal". Open it and make it clean. After that, I can download any add-on dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Doesn't work though. It seems because this phone comes with old google keyboard and after updating it doesn't accept dictionaries .. as I understand from reading so far, it might be license issue that I don't fully aware of.